# Create a new instance with same name through looping

Tags: objective-c

As novice to Objective C, I cannot really understand why this is ok:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(i)];
        NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);
    }
}
return 0;
```

But not this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(0)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);

    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(1)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);
}
return 0;
```

In both cases, I do redefine *newNumber (?) Why is it different?

Answer (score 4):

Variable names must be unique within a given scope.

A scope is defined by curly braces `{}`. Variables are only valid in the scope they are defined in (and in scopes within that scope).

If you have a loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(i)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);
}
```

`newNumber` is only available inside that for loop (between `{}`). After each iteration it is "gone".

If you have a scope like

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(0)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);

    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(1)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);
}
```

both `newNumber` variables are within the same scope and therefore **not** unique.

Comment: And the same applies for most of the other programming languages, be it Java, C++, C# or Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C only allows you to declare the *type* of a local variable once within a scope. So the following is fine:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSNumber *newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(0)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);

    newNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(1)];
    NSLog(@"New number = %@", newNumber);
}
```

In this case, the second assignment to `newNumber` changes the value of the existing pointer, rather than creating a second pointer with the same name.

Comment: I would say that Objective-C (like most languages) only allows you to declare a variable once within a scope. The type is irrelevant. In your answer, the 2nd use of `newNumber` isn't a declaration.

Comment: Yes, of course most scope-based languages follow a similar rule. I just referred to Objective-C specifically because that's what the OP asked about.

Comment: The point of my comment what that you stated "*Objective-C only allows you to declare* the type of *a local variable once within a scope.*". I'm saying the type is irrelevant. The statement should simply be "*Objective-C only allows you to declare a local variable once within a scope.*"

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. In my answer, I was adjusting my language for a beginner programmer. If you don't mention "type", then you have to also explain what a declaration is. By mentioning "type", which is the most obvious difference between a declaration and an assignment, it's immediately obvious what I'm talking about.